# Formatting CURDATE() output

Tags: sql, plsql

Is there any way to format the output of CURDATE() to give me the current date in this format: 03-21-14 (month - day - year)?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Mon-DD-YY') FROM Dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try **[Date_Format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)**

```
   SELECT Date_Format(curdate(), '%m-%d-%Y')
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/33982)**

Answer (score 0):

There is a date_format function you can use.

`SELECT date_format(curdate(), '%m-%d-%y');`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a select from database use

```
date_format(curdate(), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Else use mktime() function

Comment: ACtually I'm making an INSERT and this will be put in values field.

Comment: If in your table the  date col is set to DATETIME you can insert just something like '2004-08-15 12:41:33'. You can modify later with php when making the select.